# Transfer data from nodejs to the webpage, and fill the specific elements (search by id or class) in the web page

Tags: node.js, html, mongodb, express

I have extracted the data from the mongo database using nodejs. I just want to populate the webpage with the data extracted.

```
function requireUser(req, res, next){
//console.log(req.session.username);
 if (!req.session.username) {
   res.redirect('/user_unauthorized');
  }
 else{
   next();
  }
}

app.get('/dashboard', requireUser, function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('dashboard.html',{root: path.join(__dirname,'./')});
});

function authenticateUser(username, password, callback){
 var coll = mongo.collection('users');

 coll.find({username: username, password:password}).toArray(function(err, user){
 console.log(user);
 callback(err, user);
 }); 
}

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;

 authenticateUser(username, password, function(err, user){
  if (user.length) {
    // This way subsequent requests will know the user is logged in.
    req.session.username = user[0].username;
    console.log(req.session.username); 
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  } else {
    console.log('user not authenticated');
    res.redirect('/invalid_credentials');
  }
 });
});
```

The above code would check for a POST request from the login page.Then the user is checked for authenticity. If the user details are found in the database then user is directed to the dashboard. Now here I am stuck. I want to fill the dashboard with the details of the user. I have checked various posts on internet, but I could not find, how to fill the elements(searched by id or class or name) of the html page.

> This is my first nodejs app. Please help me out of this issue. Correct me if I am going wrong somewhere or if there is some problem with my concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the user with the response.Like,

```
res.redirect('/dashboard',{user: user});
```

And on client side you can fetch the user object in result.If you are using angular, then store the result in $scope and use that $scope with ng-model.

Otherwise, put the values individually in elements.